# How to sort a list of objects by contained enum?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, enums, comparator

I am using java 8. I have a list of car objects . I want to sort them in a specific order.
each car objects belong to a model . i like to sort the list of car objects by model. The sorted list should be in the following order , cars with models SEDAN, then followed by BMW and then UNICORN.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

enum Model {

    BMW, SEDAN, UNICORN

}

public class Car {

    private Model model;

    private int id;

    public Car(Model model, int id) {
        super();
        this.model = model;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Model getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Car> l = new ArrayList<Car>();

        Car c1 = new Car(Model.BMW, 1);
        Car c2 = new Car(Model.BMW, 2);
        Car c3 = new Car(Model.SEDAN, 3);
        Car c4 = new Car(Model.SEDAN, 4);
        Car c5 = new Car(Model.SEDAN, 5);
        Car c6 = new Car(Model.UNICORN, 6);
        Car c7 = new Car(Model.BMW, 7);
        Car c8 = new Car(Model.BMW, 8);

        l.add(c1);
        l.add(c2);
        l.add(c3);
        l.add(c4);
        l.add(c5);
        l.add(c6);
        l.add(c7);
        l.add(c8);
    }
}
```

so when i print the sorted list it should be like this

```
[Car [model=SEDAN, id=3],  Car [model=SEDAN, id=4]  ,Car [model=SEDAN, id=5],  [model=BMW, id=1], Car [model=BMW, id=2], Car [model=BMW, id=7], Car [model=BMW, id=8],  Car [model=UNICORN, id=6]]
```

How can i achieve this order of sorting on the model enum with a custom comparator.

appreciate if you can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First approach**

Reorder the enum entries so the resulting order follows your requirements:

```java
enum Model {
    SEDAN, BMW, UNICORN
}
```

then you can sort your list as follows:

```java
l.sort(Comparator.comparing(Car::getModel));
```

Note that enum values are compared by their order in code (i.e. `ordinal()`)

---

**Second approach**

Assign a value to each enum entry:

```java
enum Model {
    SEDAN(0), BMW(1), UNICORN(2);
    final int val;
    Model(int val) { this.val = val; }
}
```

then you can sort your list as follows:

```java
l.sort(Comparator.comparing((Car car) -> car.getModel().val));
```

---

Answer (score 2):

You can assign int values to enums and give them values according to the preferences you want.

Then implement `Comparable` interface for your `Car` object to sort the using these assigned `int` values for each model

**Code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
// assign enum values in ascending order here 
enum Model {
    SEDAN(0),
    BMW(1),
    UNICORN(2);

    private int value;

    private Model(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
// implement comparable class 
public class Car implements Comparable<Car> {

    private Model model;

    private int id;

    public Car(Model model, int id) {
        super();
        this.model = model;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Model getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
   // compare Cars by Model int value
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Car otherCar) {
        if (this.getModel().getValue() > otherCar.getModel().getValue())
            return 1;
        else return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "model=" + model +
                ", id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}

public static List<Car> l = new ArrayList<Car>();
Car c1 = new Car(Model.BMW, 1);
Car c2 = new Car(Model.BMW, 2);
Car c3 = new Car(Model.SEDAN, 3);
Car c4 = new Car(Model.SEDAN, 4);
Car c5 = new Car(Model.SEDAN, 5);
Car c6 = new Car(Model.UNICORN, 6);
Car c7 = new Car(Model.BMW, 7);
Car c8 = new Car(Model.BMW, 8);

l.add(c1);
l.add(c2);
l.add(c3);
l.add(c4);
l.add(c5);
l.add(c6);
l.add(c7);
l.add(c8);
l.sort(Car::compareTo);
l;
```

**Output**

```
[Car{model=SEDAN, id=5}, 
Car{model=SEDAN, id=4}, 
Car{model=SEDAN, id=3}, 
Car{model=BMW, id=8},
Car{model=BMW, id=7}, 
Car{model=BMW, id=2}, 
Car{model=BMW, id=1}, 
Car{model=UNICORN, id=6}]
```

Comment: Good Answer. For clarity, I suggest renaming `value` to something more specific such as `sortOrder`.